# Unit testing the onPageStarted and onPageFinished of a WebView's WebViewClient callbacks

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-webview

```
Android Studio 3.5.1
Kotlin 1.3
```

I have the following method that I am trying to unit test. That uses the `WebView` and `WebViewClient`

The method I have is the following that needs to be unit tested:

```
fun setPageStatus(webView: WebView?, pageStatus: (PageStatusResult) -> Unit) {
    webView?.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            pageStatus(PageStatusResult.PageStarted(url ?: "", favicon))
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            pageStatus(PageStatusResult.PageFinished(url ?: ""))
        }
    }
}
```

I takes a webView that overrides some callback from the WebViewClient. And then calls a lambda function in the onPageStarted or onPageFinished.

Uses a sealed class to set the properties that is passed in the lambda method

```
sealed class PageStatusResult {
    data class PageFinished(val url: String) : PageStatusResult()
    data class PageStarted(val url: String, val favicon: Bitmap?) : PageStatusResult()
}
```

In the unit test I have do something like this:

```
@Test
fun `should set the correct settings of the WebView`() {
    // Arrange the webView
    val webView = WebView(RuntimeEnvironment.application.baseContext)

    // Act by calling the setPageStatus
    webFragment.setPageStatus(webView) { pageStatusResult ->
        when(pageStatusResult) {
            is PageStarted -> {
            // Assert that the url is correct
                assertThat(pageStatusResult.url).isEqualToIgnoringCase("http://google.com")
            }
        }
    }

    // Call the onPageStarted on the webViewClient and and assert in the when statement
    webView.webViewClient.onPageStarted(webView, "http://google.com", null)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the nature of this unit test is async, instead of calling the `webView.webViewClient.onPageStarted` synchronously yourself, you should use an async testing approach. In this way, we pass a URL to the `WebView` to show, then wait until the `onPageStarted` method is called by the `WebView` itself.

It seems that the best option to run async unit tests in Android is using the [Awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org).

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:4.0.1'
}
```

**Unit Test Class**

```
@Test
fun `should set the correct settings of the WebView`() {

    val requestedUrl = "https://www.google.com"
    var resultUrl: String? = null

    // Arrange the webView
    val webView = WebView(RuntimeEnvironment.application.baseContext)

    // Act by calling the setPageStatus
    webFragment.setPageStatus(webView) { pageStatusResult ->
        when (pageStatusResult) {
            is PageStatusResult.PageStarted -> {
                resultUrl = pageStatusResult.url
            }
        }
    }

    // trying to load the "requestedUrl"
    webView.loadUrl(requestedUrl)

    // waiting until the "onPageStarted" is called
    await().until { resultUrl != null }

    // now check the equality of URLs
    assertThat(resultUrl).isEqualToIgnoringCase(requestedUrl)
}
```

Comment: changed the URL to `https`, because `http` might fail without a network security configuration.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without the await()? I was thinking using something like doAnswer() or something

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find something to do it without waiting for the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [kotlinx-coroutines-test](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/), you could use `CompletableDeferred` to await.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `should set the correct settings of the WebView`() = runTest {
        val urlDeferred = CompletableDeferred<String>(coroutineContext.job)

        // Arrange the webView
        val webView = WebView(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())

        // Act by calling the setPageStatus
        webFragment.setPageStatus(webView) { pageStatusResult ->
            when(pageStatusResult) {
                is PageStatusResult.PageStarted -> {
                    urlDeferred.complete(pageStatusResult.url)
                }
            }
        }

        // Call the onPageStarted on the webViewClient and and assert in the when statement
        webView.webViewClient.onPageStarted(webView, "http://google.com", null)

        // Await at most MAX_WAITING milliseconds
        val url = withTimeout(MAX_WAITING) { urlDeferred.await() }

        // Assert that the url is correct
        assertThat(url).isEqualToIgnoringCase("http://google.com")
    }
```